# VS2015 x86 LIbraries are not in OpenCV 3.1

Tags: opencv

I've just downloaded the most recent OpenCV Version from the website as I need the VC14 compiled DLLs. They don't have x86 compiled VC14 DLLs though unlike VC12.

Is there a reason for this that I am missing? Do I need to compile them myself? What's the reason for the change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no specific reason. You probably should compile it yourself.

Side notes:

1. Be aware that you can not compile it with CUDA on VS2015 until you
   have CUDA 8.0.
2. If you want to activate vtx, you should disable compiler optimization while building, which is not a good option.

Just an opinion, I think those two reasons may explain why they did not pre-built it.

Comment: oh.. now it makes more sense ;D